# Android announcing number edit text as digits

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a text field like the following:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/credit_card_number"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="number" />
```

The problem is that when TalkBack is turned on, it is announcing the value as a single number, rather than individual digits.  In this particular case, because it is a credit card, i need it to be entirely numerical (hence the inputType of "number").  However, it doesn't make sense to announce it that way for accessibility purposes.

I've been unable to find a way to get talkBack to announce as individual digits.

I've tried a custom text watcher to set the contentDescription, but nothing seems to be affecting how it's reading it out.

I've also tried an accessibility delegate, but even though it fires in the debugger, it's not changing what's read to the user:

```
cardNumberText.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(final View host, final AccessibilityEvent event) {
                event.getText().add("foobar");
                event.setContentDescription("foobar");
            }
        });
```

Has anyone else encountered and solved this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hack, haven't tried it though.
Set the `setContentDescription()` with spaces between each digit. Or you can also use `(char)160` appended between each character.

Comment: I've tried that, and not only does it not work, setting the contentDescription seems to have no effect whatsoever on the Edit Text.  It always reads out the contents.  And when the inputType is set to "number" it reads it out as a full number, not digit by digit.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this by adding a textChangeListener to the EditText and updating AccessibilityDelegate whenever the EditText updated.

```
numberField.addTextChangedListener { editable ->
        
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(
            numberField,
            object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                    info.text = editable.toString().getSpacedNumber()
                }
            })
}
```

And I added space between numbers using the following regex

```
fun String.getSpacedNumber(): String {
    return replace(".(?!$)".toRegex(), "$0  ")
}
```